# Initializing super class variable more concisely (and conveniently)

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, swift

Take a look at the code below to see what I am inquiring about.

```
class EmploymentTableViewController: UITableViewController {

        ...

        // MARK: - Initialization

        override init() {
            super.init()
            self.title = "Employment"
        }

        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            self.title = "Employment"
        }

        override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
            super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
            self.title = "Employment"
        }

        override init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
            super.init(style: style)
            self.title = "Employment"
        }

        ...

}
```

I find myself reimplementing this a lot in my view controllers. If I override just one initializer function, I must in turn reimplement it in all possible initialization functions else the program will crash.

Are there any courses of action I can take to ensure that {class}.title is set at initialization without needing to make such verbose code?

The end result is to have the title make it's way to the tab bar item it will be linked to. When adding this to a tab bar controller, the title of the tab bar item is automatically set to the title of the view controller.

Thank you,

Steven

Comment: You can set the title in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: dan, when doing that the title does not make it's way to being the title of the tab bar item it becomes a part of.

Comment: Does it work if you put it in awakeFromNib (assuming your controller is coming out of IB)?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Not even if I do that in the custom navigation controller that this view is the root of.

Comment: I tried this in one of my apps, and initWithCoder was the only one I needed to override.

Comment: @rdelmar, here is the code that is instantiating the view controller with the initWithCoder function being the only overriden init.self.employment = EmploymentTableViewController()
I get the error,
    "Missing argument for parameter 'code'  in call"

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing. When I set the title in awakeFromNib (or in initWithCoder), in a UITableViewController subclass that's embedded in a navigation controller in a tab bar controller, it works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72496/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-steven-floyd).